# Close button initiates main_load event

Tags: c#

I have multiple forms in my WinForm application.

The first form (Form1) is used for authentication, while the second (Main) is used as main dashboard for the application that opens additional forms.

When I am in designer mode, I double click on the close button within the Main form to generate the closing event, but something weird occurs.

Instead of:

```
private void Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
```

The event that the click generates is:

```
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I don't understand why.

I've tried to type the method manually as shown bellow:

```
 private void Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to quit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo); 

            if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            } else if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

        }
```

But its simply not linked to the close button.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find and delete the event assignment for the Main form Close buttton's click event. That code is going to be in the **Main.Designer.cs** module. Look for all instances of this code:

```
this.FormClosing += ...
```

Delete that assignment (or those assignments, if more than one), then go back to the form designer, double-click the Main form's close button, and Visual Studio will create and take you to the method handler for the FormClosing event.

Answer (score 0):

In the form constructor for `Main()` you can bind an event handler for the `FormClosing` event like so.

```
public Main()
{
    // other startup tasks here

    this.FormClosing += Main_FormClosing;
}

private void Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    var dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to quit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo); 

    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;
    }

    Application.Exit();

}
```